# R::How to split the data into "n" bins in R

Tags: r

I have a column of continuous values. Say 1 to 10000. I want to make it to "n" buckets in considerable range, say from 1 to 1000 - call it as bucket 1, 1000 to 5000 bucket 2 etc. Is there any package available in R to do this

Thank you

Comment: @cathG - My apologizes for posting a duplicate question. Probably i didnt used correct words to search this question. sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try `rep`.  In general, it is better to use `cut` or `findInterval`, but in this special case, `rep` also should work.

```
 rep(1:3, c(1000, 4000, 5000))
```

Comment: @Arun Thanks for your generous comments.